# Properly saving/writing and loading/reading serialized custom objects

Tags: java, android, object, serialization

I am trying to get my game app to properly save/load custom objects that a player can manipulate. I've been having an extremely difficult time just getting this to work on the most basic level, and I'm running out of ideas.

**Background**: The app I'm developing is an interactive fiction game, where the player can manipulate certain objects to advance a story. I want to allow the user to be able to return to their game state if they kill the app, so I need to save the current state of numerous objects (in this case, `Items`), and then load them the next time they play.

Currently, I am trying to do this as simply as possible, so for now I am merely trying to manipulate an object, save the object, and then load the object after killing the app to return it to the saved state.

For this specific case, the object is a `desk drawer` from custom class `Item,` which has many attributes of many data types `(string, int, boolean, arraylist)`. The drawer starts closed `(drawer.isOpen = false)`. I would like to open the drawer `(drawer.isOpen = true)`, save the serialized object `drawer`, restart the app, then load the data to retrieve the drawer state. This means that at the end of the process, my drawer should go from it's original state `closed` to its saved state "open" after pressing the load button.

The Code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.save:
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("player.ser", Context
                        .MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(drawer);
                oos.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail io", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.load:
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput("player.ser");
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                drawer = (Item) is.readObject();
                is.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail io", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no class", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
```

The Result:
I am able to get the toast message "success" both saving and loading. However, as far as I can tell, there is zero change to the app, or app data. The drawer does not change states after loading, regardless of restarting the app or not. As the operation results in a "success" there is no error code I can work from and therefore have no what's happening under the hood.

Where am I going wrong? Is this the correct way to save and load object data? I am a self-taught beginner, and have had a lot of difficulty finding information on how to do something like this.

Comment: Do the users of `drawer` know that it has been reassigned?

Comment: By users of `drawer`, do you mean the various methods that use it? If so, then I will assume that no, they don't know it has been reassigned. At least, I haven't made any specific code that would "refresh" the program after loading. If the methods need to know the `drawer` object has been reassigned, my question then becomes how do I do that?